# CategoryList attribute for predefined color ramp in pyQgs

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, color-ramp

I am trying to style my vector layer in QGIS using the following python code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
myStyle = QgsStyleV2().defaultStyle()
defaultColorRampNames = myStyle.colorRampNames()
ramp = myStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[1])
field='count'
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2(field,[])
renderer.setSourceColorRamp(ramp)

layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
if iface.mapCanvas().isCachingEnabled():
    layer.setCacheImage(None)
else:
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

But on executing this code , all features get coloured white.Now i know this is because i am passing an empty second  argument to **QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2(field,[])**.The problem is that i am not able to figure out what to pass as the second argument if i want to use the default color ramp.

Comment: `layermap = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(name)[0]` ;)

Comment: Okay ..writing the function might have been an overkill but this doesn't solve the problem i have.

Comment: It doesn't but it's just helping you write shorter code.

Comment: @NathanW Shortened the code

Answer (score 1):

Okay ..I figured out a way to do that .

I had to use **QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2** rather than **QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2**

Here is the code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
field='count'
myRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2()
myRenderer.setClassAttribute(field)
myRenderer.setMode(QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.EqualInterval)
myRenderer.updateClasses(layer,QgsGraduatedSymbolRendererV2.EqualInterval,50)
myStyle = QgsStyleV2().defaultStyle()
defaultColorRampNames = myStyle.colorRampNames()
ramp = myStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[8])

myRenderer.updateColorRamp(ramp)
layer.setRendererV2(myRenderer)
if iface.mapCanvas().isCachingEnabled():
    layer.setCacheImage(None)
else:
    iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
layer.triggerRepaint()
```